# Can't access value of hidden input with jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hidden-field

I've got the following input on my page

```
<input type='hidden' id='hdnCurrentPage' name='hdnCurrentPage' value='1' />
```

I'm calling a function on $(document).ready calling the following code

```
var currPage = $('#hdnCurrentPage').val();
```

Value is returned as blank. It's finding the element (I can look at the type attribute, for example), but I can't get the value.

It works fine in Chrome and FF.

**Update**

Not sure what exactly this means, but if I add an attribute, I can read that just fine. For example, adding "data-value='1'" to the field, I can easily access that attribute, but still not the actual value of the field.

Comment: do you get any js errors in IE?

Comment: This looks perfectly fine. How do you check the value of currPage?

Comment: I tested in 8, 9 and 10. None worked. The only error I get is when I end up passing a blank value to an ajax call when it's expecting an int.

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @KamilT, I've just been testing through the console since I discovered the problem.

Comment: I tested in 7, 8, 9 and 10 (emulated) and works fine in all

Comment: @PalashMondal I can't reproduce the issue in jsFiddle, but I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: I posted an update with some strange behavior. I initially thought it may be an issue with the timing of $(document).ready in IE, but that's clearly not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. My own dumb fault. There's a prior function that checks a cookie for data and sets the value of the input based in that. In Chrome and FF, if it's blank != "" works fine, in IE it's returned as null, so it was setting the value to null.

I figured it's only fair that I explain this and be publicly humiliated.